# Can't import value from .env file / Django

Tags: django, environment-variables

I got a file `.env` with 4 values  to hide sensitive data:

```
DATABASE_PASSWD=Password1
SECRET_KEY=Password2
VAR3=Password3
VAR4=Password4
```

All of above values are properly imported in Django code except the `DATABASE_PASSWORD`. When the `DATABASES` configuration is as follows:

```
# settings.py
from decouple import config

# ...

DB_PASSWORD=config('DATABASE_PASSWD')
SECRET_KEY=config('SECRET_KEY')

VAR3=config('VAR3')
VAR4=config('VAR4')


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': "database_name",
        'USER': "database_test_admin",
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': "localhost",
        'PORT': "5432",
    }
}
```

The django outputs:

```
raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: DATABASE_PASSWD not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

If I hardcode password that is just the same in `.env` the problem is gone - the password is correct since it's my private project. Other variables works well with the same `config('VAR#')` function in views for  example. I have no clue what could be wrong here.

Comment: from it's github page at https://github.com/HBNetwork/python-decouple, it looks like it needs cast parameter or by provide default

Comment: Are you in a position to be able to change the DB password?  I use decouple, and I have run into one strange instance over the years when a very long password with special characters didn't come through.  I changed the PW and it worked.

Comment: @whoami - From that page: `By default, all values returned by decouple are strings,` so you only need cast if you want another type.  This is why the .env file doesn't require quotes

Comment: Are you sure that `DATABASE_PASSWD` is defined in your `.env` file and not `DB_PASSWORD` or `DATABASE_PASSWORD` or `DB_PASSWD`. Make sure that the variable in `.env` matches the string you pass to `config()`. Note that your python variable is different. I recommend that you make it the same as the environment variable name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

The official docs pushed me to try this:

```
from decouple import config, AutoConfig # <-- AutoConfig added

#  ...

config = AutoConfig(search_path='.env') # <-- .env file located next to manage.py 

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DB_PASSWORD = config('DB_PASSWORD')


VAR3 = config('VAR3')
VAR4 = config('VAR4')
```

When I provided empty string by the `default` value the code started to work, however no real string was passed by `config()`  - just the default, which didi not solve anything but made django server running.